# syntax error on auto-generated code while using Spring Tool Suite

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm new to Spring-Tool-Suite, and I'm wondering how or why I would be getting syntax errors on the code that STS generated automatically when I opened up my servlet?

```
response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
}
```

The system is telling me that there is a `syntax error on token`getWriter,`identifier expected after this token.`  Is this common? What do I do?

Comment: Are you using some kind of IDE like eclipse? It should tell you if you are missing an import or a dependency.

Comment: Just spring.  I think I found it.  Apparently, when I was writing my doGet() request right above it, I accidentally closed a bracket .  THanks though... I had already spent an hour trying to research this...